# Keras sequential API: issue with calling model.predict on multiple inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm having an issue calling model.predict on a model defined using the sequential API. Seems to work OK using the functional API. Maybe this has nothing to do with sequential/functional and I just have a bug.

Using the keras sequential API with multiple inputs I have this toy model:

```
left_branch = keras.models.Sequential()
left_branch.add(keras.layers.Dense(32, input_dim=784))

right_branch = keras.models.Sequential()
right_branch.add(keras.layers.Dense(32, input_dim=784))

merged = keras.layers.Concatenate([left_branch, right_branch])

final_model = keras.models.Sequential()
final_model.add(merged)
final_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

When I call model.predict like this:

```
x1 = np.random.random_sample(size = [1,784])
x2 = np.random.random_sample(size = [1,784])
final_model.predict([x1,x2])
```

I'm getting the error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`, even though both list items are np arrays. The full error is below.

The error does *NOT* happen when I code up the same model in the functional API like this:

```
x1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(784,))
left_branch = keras.layers.Dense(32)(x1)

x2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(784,))
right_branch = keras.layers.Dense(32)(x2)

merged = keras.layers.Concatenate()([x1, x2])
out = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(merged)

final_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[x1, x2], outputs=out)
```

Here's the full error output from the sequential model:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-4b45e1bec6dd> in <module>()
      1 x1 = np.random.random_sample(size = [1,784])
      2 x2 = np.random.random_sample(size = [1,784])
----> 3 final_model.predict([x1,x2])

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.pyc in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps)
   1750     # Validate and standardize user data.
   1751     x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(
-> 1752         x, check_steps=True, steps_name='steps', steps=steps)
   1753 
   1754     if context.executing_eagerly():

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.pyc in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split)
    991       x, y = next_element
    992     x, y, sample_weights = self._standardize_weights(x, y, sample_weight,
--> 993                                                      class_weight, batch_size)
    994     return x, y, sample_weights
    995 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.pyc in _standardize_weights(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size)
   1027       if not self.inputs:
   1028         is_build_called = True
-> 1029         self._set_inputs(x)
   1030 
   1031     if y is not None:

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable/base.pyc in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    424     self._setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    425     try:
--> 426       method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    427     finally:
    428       self._setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.pyc in _set_inputs(self, inputs, training)
   1219         self.build(input_shape=input_shape)
   1220       else:
-> 1221         input_shape = (None,) + inputs.shape[1:]
   1222         self.build(input_shape=input_shape)
   1223     if context.executing_eagerly():

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: You can't have a concatenation layer in a Sequential model, since it would be no longer a Sequential model.

Comment: I was following this guide: https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.2.2/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#the-merge-layer
Is this no longer relevant in later keras?

Comment: That is an old version of Keras (1.2.2). The latest Keras version is 2.2.4 and it no longer has a `Merge` layer at all :)